# Multi Foreign Key from same Model

Tags: django-models, foreign-keys

I have a model named service, Another model named Deal. In the deal Model, I have two fields. The first one is older_service, and the second field is new_service. Both are related to the same Model (service), but when I make the migrations, it throws the following error :

AssertionError: ForeignKey(<django.db.models.fields.related.ForeignKey>) is invalid. First parameter to ForeignKey must be either a model, a model name, or the string
'self'

Any Help, please.

Comment: Hi Abdulbasit Almomen, welcome to StackOverflow. Please read the following helpful information: [tour], [ask] and [mre].

Answer (score 0):

you have tow foreignkey as same name